# Paperclip not called when uploading attachment, so attachment is not saved. Rails3 + uploadify

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, attachment, uploadify

I have two different apps using paperclip. On the app that does not save attachment or call paperclip, i get this log when i upload an app

```
started POST "/users/1/uploads" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-23 13:38:11 +0100
Processing by UploadsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“",    "authenticity_token"=>"t2dRIH4FgOPnLRhpDK0x7iIfjB9Xj5rqkJRPCWZvJ14=", "upload"=> {"document"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x2beeb08 @original_filename="Essay  questions have various requirements.doc", @content_type="application/msword",  @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload[document]\"; filename=\"Essay  questions have various requirements.doc\"\r\nContent-Type: application/msword\r\n",  @tempfile=#<File:C:/DOCUME~1/Ed/LOCALS~1/Temp/RackMultipart20110423-3980-ycq74p>>},  "commit"=>"Upload", "user_id"=>"1"}
[1m[35mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
[1m[36mUpload Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "uploads".* FROM "uploads" WHERE  ("uploads".uploadable_id = 1 AND "uploads".uploadable_type = 'User')[0m
Rendered uploads/_uploadify.html.erb (15.6ms)
Rendered uploads/_form.html.erb (31.2ms)
Rendered uploads/new.html.erb within layouts/application (46.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 500ms (Views: 234.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

On the app where paperclip works fine, i get this log:

```
Started POST "/uploads" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Apr 25 11:35:50 +0100 2011
Processing by UploadsController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"_http_accept"=>"application/javascript", "Filename"=>"angels.txt",    "folder"=>"/users/", "authenticity_token"=>"NVJj3ODIGuoc97wGvjWkez1YoN+SUDVtNJ+k80XdYXM=", "Upload"=>"Submit Query", "user_id"=>"1", "_uploadify_session"=>"BAh7ByIQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4iMU5WSmozT0RJR3VvYzk3d0d2aldrZXoxWW9OK1NVRFZ0TkorazgwWGRZWE09Ig9zZXNzaW9uX2lkIiU0ZDEyNzZkNzczNzk1MDdiMmQ4NWZmYTY5MDY4YTU0MQ==--7eb8c0ca249e2566998a0e68322a89d731fdb4ad", "Filedata"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x4958490 @content_type="application/octet-stream", @original_filename="angels.txt", @tempfile=#<File:C:/DOCUME~1/Ed/LOCALS~1/Temp/RackMultipart20110425-4884-vyvdo8-0>, @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Filedata\"; filename=\"angels.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n">}
[paperclip] identify -format %wx%h "C:/DOCUME~1/Ed/LOCALS~1 /Temp/stream20110425-4884-15he32x-0.txt[0]" 2>NUL
[paperclip] convert "C:/DOCUME~1/Ed/LOCALS~1/Temp/stream20110425-4884-15he32x-0.txt[0]" -resize "300x300>" "C:/DOCUME~1/Ed/LOCALS~1/Temp/stream20110425-4884-15he32x-020110425-4884-r65fe6-0" 2>NUL
[paperclip] identify -format %wx%h "C:/DOCUME~1/Ed/LOCALS~1/Temp/stream20110425-4884-15he32x-0.txt[0]" 2>NUL
[paperclip] convert "C:/DOCUME~1/Ed/LOCALS~1/Temp/stream20110425-4884-15he32x-0.txt[0]" -resize "100x100>" "C:/DOCUME~1/Ed/LOCALS~1/Temp/stream20110425-4884-15he32x-020110425-4884-1ttxfol-0" 2>NUL
[1m[36mAREL (15.6ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "uploads" ("user_id", "created_at", "photo_file_size", "photo_updated_at", "photo_content_type", "photo_file_name", "updated_at") VALUES (1, '2011-04-25 10:36:10.312500', 867, '2011-04-25 10:35:52.109375', 'text/plain', 'angels.txt', '2011-04-25 10:36:10.312500')[0m
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
[paperclip] saving C:/rails_project1/Uploadify-2/public/system/photos/2/medium/angels.txt
[paperclip] saving C:/rails_project1/Uploadify-2/public/system/photos/2/thumb/angels.txt
[paperclip] saving C:/rails_project1/Uploadify-2/public/system/photos/2/original/angels.txt
Completed 200 OK in 19422ms (Views: 62.5ms | ActiveRecord: 15.6ms)
```

The only difference between the two is that the one not working is polymorphic model and the controller for the polymorphic model is below:

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_parent
  before_filter :prepare_input_params
  #respond_to :html, :json, :js

  def index
     @uploads = Upload.all
 #@uploads = @parent.try(:uploads).try(:all)
 @upload = Upload.new
     #respond_with([@parent, @uploads])
  end

  def new
     @upload = @parent.uploads.new
  end

  def create 
     @upload = @parent.uploads.build(params[:upload])   
   if @upload.save
        flash[:notice] = "sucessfully saved upload"     
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to [@parent, :uploads]}
        format.json {render :json => { :result => 'success', :upload =>  polymorphic_url([@parent,:uploads])  } }
      end   
  else
      render :action => 'new'
      end
 end

 def edit
   @upload = Upload.find(params[:id])   
 end

 def show
   "puts @upload.inspect"
     @upload = @parent.uploads.find(params[:id])
     @total_uploads = @parent.uploads.find(:all, :conditions => { :user_id =>  @upload.user.id})
 end

 def update
   @upload = Upload.find(params[:id])
    if @upload.update_attributes(params[:upload])
     flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated document"
     redirect_to @upload
    else
     render :action => 'edit'
    end
 end

 def destroy
   @upload = Upload.find(params[:id])
   @upload.destroy
   redirect_to([@parent, :upload])
 end 

 private 
 def prepare_input_params
   params[:upload][:document] = params[:Filedata] if params[:Filedata]
 end
```

end

Here is the gist file with the form partial and uploadify bit: https://gist.github.com/940960. The form has :html => { :multipart => true }.

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**:

It seems the problem is from the model, uploads.rb. When i comment out the section below: everything works, but i need to be able to use validations and specify path as i want to use S3. Anyhelp on how i can uncomment the code without the initial error of paperclip not saving happening again.

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible  :document
 belongs_to :uploadable,  :polymorphic => true
 has_attached_file :document, :styles => { :small => "150x150>",:thumb => "100x100>" }
=begin                 
             :url => "/uploads/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
             :path => ":rails.root/public/:uploads/:id/:style/:basement.:extension"                                  
validates_attachment_presence :document
validates_attachment_size  :document, :less_than => 5.megabytes
validates_attachment_content_type :document, :content_type => ['application/octet-stream','image/jpeg','image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/pdf', 'image/doc', 
                                                             'video/x-m4v', 'video/quicktime','application/x-shockwave-flash', 'audio/mpeg', 'video/mpeg', 'application/pdf','application/msword']

=end
```

end

**Update**:

I think the main problem seem to be that why attaching a new file, paperclip, somehow starts calling **SELECT "uploads".*'from "uploads"** instead of calling **INSERT INTO 'uploads'**, that is **controller#create action** shown higher up seems to be calling SELECT, whenever ever i provide :url and :path options to paperclip has_attached_file method. See the log below:

```
Processing by UploadsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"Azxzi09R7NU7+jxj+lxHFGfs+qw7D6b7yRKegRjRQMc=", "upload"=> {"document"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x2994ff0 @original_filename="al night  verses.txt", @content_type="text/plain", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;  name=\"upload[document]\"; filename=\"al night verses.txt\"\r\nContent-Type:  text/plain\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:C:/DOCUME~1/Ed/LOCALS~1 /Temp/RackMultipart20110505-3444-1rlpnr>>}, "commit"=>"Upload", "user_id"=>"1"}
[1m[35mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
[paperclip] C:\ImageMagick-6.6.3-Q16/identify -format %wx%h "C:/DOCUME~1/Ed/LOCALS~1 /Temp/stream20110505-3444-1cpnf87.txt[0]"
[paperclip] C:\ImageMagick-6.6.3-Q16/convert "C:/DOCUME~1/Ed/LOCALS~1 /Temp/stream20110505-3444-1cpnf87.txt[0]" -resize "150x150>" "C:/DOCUME~1/Ed/LOCALS~1 /Temp/stream20110505-3444-1cpnf8720110505-3444-1vnp5jx"
[paperclip] C:\ImageMagick-6.6.3-Q16/identify -format %wx%h "C:/DOCUME~1/Ed/LOCALS~1 /Temp/stream20110505-3444-1cpnf87.txt[0]"
[paperclip] C:\ImageMagick-6.6.3-Q16/convert "C:/DOCUME~1/Ed/LOCALS~1 /Temp/stream20110505-3444-1cpnf87.txt[0]" -resize "100x100>" "C:/DOCUME~1/Ed/LOCALS~1 /Temp/stream20110505-3444-1cpnf8720110505-3444-1vyk9i"
 [1m[36mUpload Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "uploads".* FROM "uploads" WHERE  ("uploads".uploadable_id = 1 AND "uploads".uploadable_type = 'User')[0m
Rendered uploads/_uploadify.html.erb (15.6ms)
Rendered uploads/_form.html.erb (31.2ms)
Rendered uploads/new.html.erb within layouts/application (62.5ms)
```

**Based on @CharlieMezak's request, here is the views/uploads/_form.html.erb**:

```
<%= debug @parent %>
<%= render :partial => "uploads/uploadify" %>
</br>
<%= form_for [parent, upload], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|  %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :document %><br />
<%= f.file_field :document %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit "Upload"%>
</div>
```

**views/uploads/new.html.erb**:

```
<%= render 'form', :parent => @parent, :upload => @upload %>
```

**views/users/index.html.erb**:

```
<%= render "uploads/form", :parent => user, :upload => user.uploads.new %>
```

**More Update** :

Like i mentioned, when i comment out the **:styles, : :url and :path** options from paperclips's **'has_many_attachment :document', the INSERT statement is called and though it saves the file, instead of displaying the attached file, it ends up displaying several parameters like authenticity tokens etc on the website as shown below:

```
attributes:
id: 1
email: xyz@yahoo.com
encrypted_password: $2a$10$HiksbkRXDtcXiJyUIRj
password_salt: $2a$10$HiksbkRXD
reset_password_token: !!null 
remember_token: !!null 
remember_created_at: !!null 
sign_in_count: 3
current_sign_in_at: '2011-04-25 18:57:27.078125'
last_sign_in_at: '2011-04-25 09:25:31.406250'
current_sign_in_ip: 127.0.0.1
last_sign_in_ip: 127.0.0.1
created_at: '2011-04-09 17:46:15.546875'
updated_at: '2011-04-25 18:57:27.078125'
changed_attributes: {}
previously_changed: {}
attributes_cache: {}
marked_for_destruction: false
destroyed: false
readonly: false
new_record: false
```

Comment: Can we actually see your form code?

Comment: Is the `SELECT` statement not there to grab user info to verify the auth token?

Comment: @CharlieMezak, Thanks for placing a bounty on this question. The form partial and other view files are attached.

Comment: @Joseph. Thanks but i don't think the **SELECT** statement is there to grab the user, because when i comment out the **:url** and **:path** options from **paperclips's **'has_many_attachment :document'**, the **INSERT** statement is called and though it saves the file, it ends up displaying my password, authenticity tokens etc on the website.

Comment: Ahh I see, well we definitely don't want that happening

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to add `:multipart => true` to the form tag in your view?

Comment: hah i was going to suggest the same thing. that one has gotten me more than once!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding :document_file_name to the attr_accessible call.

Comment: thanks but after adding :document_file_name to the attr_accessible call, it still will not work properly unless i comment out the 'has_attached_file :document' section and the validations.

Comment: Oh well, just an idea. I had a difficult bug before when I didn't have :document as an attr_accessible.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is there is a typo on line 17 of uploadify in your gist.  You have dat.upload, probably should be data.upload?

Also, have you tried uncommenting the validations one at a time?  Let me know what happens.  I've had my fair share of battles versus Paperclip.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I have corrected the spelling and checked the validations which seem okay now, but attachments will still not work if 'has_attached_file :document' has any options. Additional i see two routing errors. One is when Paperclip calls 'SELECT' instead of 'INSERT' and secondly when i call localhost:3000/users/1/uploads, it instead calls uploads/index.html.erb. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing exactly the same kind of thing as you are, but using the aws-s3 gem to help me upload to S3 via paperclip. This is what's in my model:

```
has_attached_file :image,
                :storage => :s3,
                :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/s3.yml",
                :bucket => "your_s3_bucket_name",
                :path => ":attachment/:id/:style/:filename"
```

And I have this in my gemfile:

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 2.3"

gem "aws-s3"
```

And in my groups table:

```
t.string   "image_file_name"
t.string   "image_content_type"
t.integer  "image_file_size"
t.datetime "image_updated_at"
```

Comment: thanks. Are you suggesting usinh **has_attached_file :document'. I ran **rails generate paperclip upload document** instead of **rails generate paperclip upload image**. Do you think **document** is a reserved word in rails. Thanks again.